# ASP.NET MVC 3 and Wordpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wordpress

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application and a separate WordPress Website. I want to integrate WordPress with my MVC site such as, if I would update any information in my MVC application, the WordPress site would be updated automatically.
Any idea for proceed?

Answer (score 0):

On Google I found something about Remote Publishing using XML-RPC, is that what you need?

Comment: yes exactly, I am using XML-RPC, but its throwing error such as "401,you cannot publish to this site", though I'm giving admin credentials for connection!

Comment: I've never used XML-RPC, so I can't help you with that :)